# How to prepare renderable array for images that are not stored in public or private filesystem, but are delivered statically with module?

Tags: media, theming

I have a piece of code that prepares renderable array for my images:

```
if( !empty($row['image_file_id'])) {
  $row['thumbnail'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#path' => _mymodule_uri_by_id((integer)$row['image_file_id']),
    '#style_name' => 'product_thumbnail_small',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'alt' => $row['image_alt'],
      'title' => $row['image_title'],
    ),
  );
}
```

It works OK:

[image: Screenshot to show it works OK]

But I want to add `else` with image provided within a module. I still want this image to go thorough all image style processing etc. I want my theming colleagues to be able to simply not care if they'll ever decide to add some effects or change resolution. But of course this image is in module directory, not in `public://`. And it means this will not work:

```
else {
  $row['thumbnail'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/frontend/noimage.png',
    '#style_name' => 'product_thumbnail_small',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'alt' => 'some universal stub',
      'title' => 'some universal stub',
    ),
  );
}
```

It gives:

[image: Screenshot to show how it fails]

And browser tries to read that image from http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_thumbnail_small/public//sites/default/modules/mymodule/frontend/noimage.png?itok=-yYlM4ns

This gives nothing (status reports says "access denied"), unless I manually place image in `public://sites/default/modules/mymodule/frontend` - but I don't want it to be in public file system, I want it to stay in module space. How can I make it work?

Comment: I'm sure I had this working once, in another project. Probably something obvious I just fail to find proper Google query for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put...you can't, unfortunately (well not without changing some core stuff at least)

From the comments for [`theme_image_style()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

> This function does not work with images outside the files directory nor with remotely hosted images.

Comment: I almost can. Marked this question as a duplicate of the one that gave me a working solution. Too bad this can't work out of the box, good there is feasible workaround

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar ;) Are you opposed to me merging this with the duplicate?

Comment: Would I vote to close as a duplicate myself? ;) Merge if you feel like, I think basically they are the same question, just needed to search for function, not render array.

Comment: Cool, will sort it out later